# Rate system warning mysql_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php

Hi everyone I'm kind of a beginner and do not know how to solve this problem. I'm trying to create rate system. He almost got it done is there is a problem and do not know how to proceed. For any assistance really thank you.

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hry"); 
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rate_db[] = $data;
        $sum_rates[] = $data['rate'];
    }
    if(@count($rate_db)){
        $rate_times = count($rate_db);
        $sum_rates = array_sum($sum_rates);
        $rate_value = $sum_rates/$rate_times;
        $rate_bg = (($rate_value)/5)*100;
    }else{
        $rate_times = 0;
        $rate_value = 0;
        $rate_bg = 0;
    }
?>
```

**Here's the error:**

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc () expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in /data/web/virtuals/88892/virtual/www/domains/viveregames.cz/pohledy/clanek.phtml  
on line 28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error means that your query failed.

Because when a query fails, mysql_query() returns false and false, as I think you know, is a boolean..

Well, also you are using mysql syntax that is deprecated.

I suggest you to use pdo or mysqli.

Also I don't see connections to database...

If you aren't connected to any db, mysql_query returns false.

Then, the code that you shown to us is completed? Or you are missing any things like connection, select db and others?

If the answer to my question is yes then:

Add these simple code lines before your actual code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');

if (!$conn) {
    die ('Error while attempting connection to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Error while selecting db: " . mysql_error());
}
```

If the answer to my question is no, please edit your post adding ALL code lines.